# How can you grow Hops (for beer) in an aquaponics system?

Tags: aquaponics

A buddy of mine is interested in attempting to grow Hops in an aquaponic system.  He is particularly interested in something of the deep water culture style of system.  Is this possible with Hops?  If so - what methods have been successful with this?

Answer (score 3):

I think deep water systems, if I understand them correctly, would be problematic because hops plants become quite large (larger, perhaps, than cucumber plants!).  Now it might be possible with proper training and support, since these are vines, but that's where your limitations are likely to be.

Comment: I don't know how large cucumber plants are, but hops plants are indeed vines which I've only seen about 3 metres tall.